# Shadow on UITableViewCell is giving bad performance

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, shadow, shadowpath

I'm creating table view with custom cells, which looks like news feed - on gray background there are rectangles with rounded corners and shadow.

While `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is calling I'm setting shadow like this:

```
cell.postCard.layer.cornerRadius = 3
cell.postCard.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
cell.postCard.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,1)
cell.postCard.layer.shadowRadius = 3
cell.postCard.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
cell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: cell.postCard.layer.bounds).CGPath
```

Where postCard is UIView - it's container for all context of cell.

I've read that I need to add shadowPath to get good performance but I think it's not working because when I'm slowly moving table view is stuttering. Can be reason of using simulator than real device?

Comment: Are you sure its the shadow and not the rounded corners?

Comment: Is it a way to improve setting corners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting shadow path to cell's layer, while modifying shadow settings for cell.postCard

```
cell.postCard.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
cell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: cell.postCard.layer.bounds).CGPath
```

Is this really what you need?

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't my intention. Fortunately it improved performance, but the shadow is not correctly sized, I mean its smaller than postCard.

Comment: You always can play with the shadow size in by increasing the rect. Use CGRectInset: rect = CGRectInset(rect, -increaseBy, -increaseBy)

Comment: Height for the cells is dynamically creating. Some of the cells has shadow in a background in good size, I don't know why it's not woring

Answer (score 0):

Also, you should set 'cell.clipsToBounds = false' for your cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try to [read](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410905-shouldrasterize) about the `should​Rasterize` and how it is working with shadows and corner radius of the UI elements. You can boost performance by manipulation of the `should​Rasterize` value.